# Connecting to and executing queries on a timescsleDB running in an EC2 or Lightsail instance from a Lambda function

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, timescaledb

I am planning to have a timescale database running in an EC2 or Lightsail instance. I would like to be able to connect to and run queries on this timescale database from a Lambda function to insert data into and read data from the DB.

I know timescaleDB is a Postgres plugin and there are plenty of articles online documenting the process of connecting to a Postgres DB running inside of AWS RDS from a lambda, but I can't seem to find any describing how I would connect to one running in an EC2 or Lightsail instance.

Question: How do I connect to a timescaleDB running in an EC2 or Lightsail instance from a lambda function?

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it more clear that I need to connect to the DB from a lambda function. I'll update the question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say the answer is the same as for how to connect to RDS, as documented here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc-rds.html

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52422395/connecting-to-amazon-rds-with-psycopg2-via-lambda) also gives a good example how to connect to a PostgreSQL RDS, but instead of using the `rds_config`, you'll need to specify the hostname/ip in such a way that they point to your EC2 instance.

The differences being that you will need to specify the hostname/ip and other connection details to point to the EC2 instance. For example, if your EC2 instances

```py
import sys, logging, psycopg2

host = "ec2-3-14-229-184.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com"
name = "demo_user"
password = "p@assword"
db_name = "demo"

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(host=host,
                        database=db_name,
                        user=name,
                        password=password)
    cur = conn.cursor()

except:
    logger.error("ERROR: Unexpected error: Could not connect to Postgresql instance.")
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. 
I'll give it a try and report back.

Comment: I ended up using the method described here : https://medium.com/@ly.lee/connecting-aws-lambda-node-js-to-redshift-or-postgresql-try-aws-lambda-layers-78e60c27f39b